# How $ d \vec s = d \vec \theta × \vec r $

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Here:-
$ d \vec s $  = infinitesimal linear displacement,
$ d \vec \theta $ = corresponding infinitesimal angular displacement,
$\vec r $ = radius vector

I am trying to understand the proof of work done due to torque, which is given by $ W = \int_{\theta 1}^{\theta 2} \tau \ d \theta $, from [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) Wikipedia page.

I know that $S = r \theta$, but I am not able to understand how $ d \vec s = d \vec \theta × \vec r $, specifically why there is a cross product.

Comment: You get the direction of $\vec{ds}$ by right hand rule and modulus of $\vec{ds}$ by geometric definition of angle.

Comment: It is literally the definition of angle in radians: what exactly is puzzling you?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

$$\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}$$

with:

$\vec{v}=\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt}$

and

$\vec{\omega}=\frac{d\vec{\Phi}}{dt}$

you  get:

$$\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt}=\frac{d\vec{\Phi}}{dt}\times \vec{r}$$
or 
$$\boxed{{d\vec{s}}={d\vec{\Phi}} \times \vec{r}}\quad \surd$$